# How can I remove the search bar at footer added to top?

Tags: datatables

I want to move the search bar which is at bottom of the data table in admin template to top ..
as this is defined in javascript .. any suggestion pls..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking this piece of code from the link you provided.

```
/*
* Set DOM structure for table controls
* @url http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/dom.html
*/
sDom: '<"block-controls"<"controls-buttons"p>>rti<"block-footer clearfix"lf>',
```

Here you can see this `sDom` right. Thats the option in datatable used to set the Table structure and to place the sections accordingly. I would suggest you to take a look at **[Datatables Dom Settings](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)**

The letters you see in the settings are `p` , `r`,`t`, `i`, `l`, `f`. They actually mean

- p - pagination control
- r - processing display element
- t - The table!
- i - Table information summary
- l - length changing input control
- f - filtering input

So by replacing this Dom settings you should be able to place the items as you wish.

So what you would need is .

```
sDom: 'lftir'
```

Add the div's and styling accordingly as explained in the **Markup** and **Styling** in the above provided link.

Comment: that really helped me.. i dont have option to give +1 as because of reputation should be more than 15..

Comment: @bcools you can still mark it as answer if this was the right solution to your problem.